# Windbg issue loading pdb for user defined executable

Tags: c++, windbg

I have a c++ executable for windows and a minidump that I am trying to analyze using windbg.
I copied the assosciated pdb and minidump into the same folder and set the symbol path.
Windbg however complains 
DBGHELP: c:\logs\marketdepthserver crashdump\SFMarketDepthServer.pdb - E_PDB_CORRUPT
Besides concluding the file is corrupt.. is there anything else I can determine from this or is there a workaround that will allow me to load the pdb.

Comment: How did you actually create the minidump?  It sounds like the file is hosed.

Comment: Should be because the pdb file doesn't have the matching, debugging and project state information, of the exe you are trying to debug. Try rebuilding it and reload all the debug information. http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/29556394/ntdllpdb--epdbcorrupt.aspx

Answer (score 8):

- !sym noisy : tells you why you failed to load symbols
- .reload /f foo.exe - to force load
- .reload /f /i foo.exe - to force load with mismatched symbols. This may give you some valuable info.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer, but this might work for you as well..

I also got this error long time back. I don't know the reason/solution for this, but I remember that I copied both the files (.exe and .pdb) to a new folder and then reloaded symbols (.reload) after specifying the new symbol path (.sympath) and that worked. (Rebuilding was also not working).